How to match column on timestamp and temporal in java spring boot
Here is my entity which is saving the timestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date transactionTime;

and here is my Service layer to fetch the data based on transactionDate
Timestamp transactionTimeStamp = new Timestamp(record.getTransactionDate().getTime());
        Result result  = repository.findByDate(transactionTimeStamp).orElse(null);

Here is my repository layer
@Query("select tr from record tr where tr.transactionDate = :transactionDate")
    Optional<Result> findByDate(@Param("transactionDate") Timestamp transactionDate);

Although query generated in the logs I am able to fetch the data
but in code I am not able to get any data and its always null.
Not sure what is the reason.
I am using mysql database
Script to create table has this line
 transaction_date                   DATETIME,


Why shoehorn it into a Timestamp? Don;t use sql types in your code, also you should be using the new java.time types the Date is flawed by design.
